# Eclipse plugin developement | Contains: Nature does not exist

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating an customized eclipse plugin.

While adding nature to project I am getting this exception:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered while setting project description.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.setDescription(Project.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.setDescription(Project.java:1378)
    at projectwizard.ProjectWizardManager.createProjectNature(ProjectWizardManager.java:72)
    at projectwizard.ProjectWizardManager.createProject(ProjectWizardManager.java:48)
    at projectwizard.NewMobilePlatformProjectWizard.performFinish(NewMobilePlatformProjectWizard.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1521)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4640)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_CHAR(Tree.java:5967)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4528)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5963)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Contains: Nature does not exist: com.mobile.platform.application.
```

Here is my plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="com.mobile.platform.plugin.newprojectwizrd"
         point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards" >
      <category
            id="eclipseplugin.com.mpp.ui.wizard" name="Mobile Platform">

      </category>
       <wizard
            category="eclipseplugin.com.mpp.ui.wizard"
            class="projectwizard.NewMobilePlatformProjectWizard"
            icon="icons/applogo.png"
            id="eclipseplugin.com.mpp.ui.wizard.NewApplicationWizard"
            name="Mobile Platform Application"
            project="true">
      </wizard>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="com.mobile.platform.application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
      <runtime>
         <run
               class="com.mobile.platform.plugin.ProjectNature">
         </run>
      </runtime>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

To add nature in newly created project here is the code:

```
private void createProjectNature(IProject project) throws CoreException {
        if (!project.hasNature(ProjectNature.NATURE_ID)) {
            IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
            String[] prevNatures = description.getNatureIds();
            String[] newNatures = new String[prevNatures.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(prevNatures, 0, newNatures, 0, prevNatures.length);
            newNatures[prevNatures.length] = ProjectNature.NATURE_ID;
            description.setNatureIds(newNatures);
            project.setDescription(description, new NullProgressMonitor());
        }

    }
```

In create project nature while it do project.setdescription, It throws the exception as dictated above.

Here is the ProjectNature class:

```
public class ProjectNature implements IProjectNature {

    public static final String NATURE_ID = "com.mobile.platform.application";
    private IProject iProject;
    @Override
    public void configure() throws CoreException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void deconfigure() throws CoreException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IProject getProject() {
        return iProject;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProject(IProject project) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.iProject=project;
    }

}
```

I am not getting what this is missing.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is name/id of your plugin?

Comment: com.mobile.platform.plugin ..I guess It is something related to id of extension issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename your project nature id `com.mobile.platform.application` in extension declaration into e.g. `mobileNature` :

```
<extension
     id="mobileNature"
     point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
  <runtime>
     <run
           class="com.mobile.platform.plugin.ProjectNature">
     </run>
  </runtime>
```

and update `NATURE_ID` accordingly

```
public class ProjectNature implements IProjectNature {

    public static final String NATURE_ID = "com.mobile.platform.plugin.mobileNature";
```